# Redirecting non-www to www doesnt work for the home page

Tags: .htaccess, dns

Im redirecting example.com/dir/anypage.html to www.example.com/dir/anypage.html (same page).

I have the following in .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^example.com [nocase]
RewriteRule ^(.*)         http://www.example.com/$1 [last,redirect=301]
```

However is not redirecting (the home page) example.com to http://www.example.com

Im missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]